# no websites loading using iptables nat

Tags: linux, nat, iptables

I'm using a 3G modem whilst o2 tranfer over adsl. trouble is no websites load but I can resolve domains. I enabled masquerade on the PPP0 ( modem) interface. added the server as default route for all workstations.

iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o ppp0 -j MASQUERADE

net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1″ to /etc/sysctl.conf

why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you get to the remote system's tcp port 80?

```
#any of these would work.
telnet www.google.com 80
echo > /dev/tcp/www.google.com/80
nc www.google.com 80
```

What does your iptables filter table look like?

```
iptables -L
```

Have you tried purging your iptables filter?

```
iptables -P INPUT ACCEPT
iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
iptables -F INPUT
iptables -F OUTPUT
```

Comment: I only have one rule thats listed when I execute  iptables -L and thats's ACCEPT all -- anywhere anywhere. It's to allow connection from the rest of my lan into the server. My server has no monitor so I'm using ssh.  When I was downloading using wget it couldn't connect. I also can't ping external ip's.  But it works fine on the server.

Comment: I'm using my adsl router to issue ip's to the workstations, does this matter? It does have nat disabled so it should be a standard router. At least that's what the manual said. The chains are flushed automatically within the startup scripts. I'm also found some errors in the /var/log/messages file. My kernel doesn't support ppp filtering and pppd can't determine remote ip.

Comment: Then you might want to set some routs and see if those will work.

Comment: yeah sorry I gathered that. It wasn't clear on the tutorial. I was using ipmasq but by default it blocked everything and so I couldn't connect to my server. I removed all the rules to isolate which rules are blocking ssh. Also for some reason the ip forward wasn't sticking as well despite I added it sysconfig.